# Comparer create lambda function cannot implicitly convert type CS0029

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, compiler-errors, compare

I'm trying to add a comparer for a data structure like so:

```
    private SortedSet<int> sortedScore = new SortedSet<int>(Comparer<int>.Create(
        (a, b) => a > b));
```

But I'm getting: CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int'

Which is strange because `a > b` is a boolean, not an int, even a cast doesn't help, but if I do:

```
    private SortedSet<int> sortedScore = new SortedSet<int>(Comparer<int>.Create(
        (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)));
```

I get no errors and actually, anything other than that get me the same error as above. So How can I change the comparer to be anything other than the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacuse an `IComparer<T>` must provide a method

```
int Compare(T x, T y)
```

I.e., it must return an `int`, not a `bool`.

- It must return an `int > 0` if `a > b`.
- It must return `0` if `a = b`.
- It must return an `int < 0` if `a < b`.

Your second example uses `a.CompareTo(b)` which does return the required `int`.

If you want to implement your own logic, you can write the lambda as:

```
(a, b) => a > b ? +1 : a < b ? -1 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of your data structure is of `SortedSet<int>`. So the comparer you could only use should implement the `IComparer<int>` interface. This interface has a method called `Compare` with the following signature:

```
int Compare(int x, int y)
```

and compares the two values `x` and `y` and returns a value indicating whether one is less than, equal to, or greater than the other. For furhre info, please have a look [IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3(v=vs.110).aspx).

That being said you can't use a method that returns a `bool`. This is why you get this error message.